Unable to connect to US_GOV national cloud with MSGraph-PHP-SDK
I am trying to connect to MSGraph in a PHP script using their SDK.
I've tried the method described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/national-clouds?tabs=PHP
Which does not seem to have any effect. I'm unable to connect and pull data with Graph.
I have made sure I can connect to my tenant using PHP + Curl methods. I'm able to pull down information.  If I try to connect and pull data, say like a user account, then the best I can get is this error: AADSTS900382: Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request.
I would very much like to use the Graph SDK directly rather than trying to work with direct calls to the Graph REST API.
An example Script is as follows:
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Microsoft\Graph\Core\NationalCloud;
    use Microsoft\Graph\GraphServiceClient;
    use Microsoft\Kiota\Authentication\Oauth\ClientCredentialContext;
    use Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Users\Item\Calendar\Events\EventsRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration;
    use Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Users\UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration;

    $scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.us/.default'];

    // Values from app registration
    $clientId = 'MY CLIENT ID';
    $tenantId = 'MY TENANT ID';
    $clientSecret = 'MY CLIENT SECRET';

    $tokenRequestContext = new ClientCredentialContext($tenantId, $clientId,    $clientSecret);


    $graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext, $scopes, NationalCloud::US_GOV);
    $user = $graphServiceClient->users('USER@MYDOMAIN.COM')->get();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($user);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>

I have tried various examples of the above script.
I have also tried to work out the proper syntax to define a custom endpoint But I'm unable to work out the proper syntax with a request adapter:
$graphClient = GraphServiceClient::createWithRequestAdapter($adapter);

Edit to add some further diagnostics and results.
$testauthprovider = new GraphPhpLeagueAuthenticationProvider (
    $tokenRequestContext, $scopes, NationalCloud::US_GOV
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($testauthprovider);
echo "</pre>";

$testtokenprovider = new GraphPhpLeagueAccessTokenProvider (
    $tokenRequestContext, $scopes, NationalCloud::US_GOV
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";

I am finding in the library that GraphPHPLeagueAuthenticationProvider and GraphPHPLeageAccessTokenProvider are both used during GraphServiceClient.
I am finding that if I input the proper parameters into GraphPHPLeagueAccessTokenProvider, then the output is correct in that I see my baseurl's reflected for NationalCloud :: US_GOV.  The important parts looking like this:
urlAuthorize:League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider:private] => https://login.microsoftonline.us/MY TENANT ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
            [urlAccessToken:League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider:private] => https://login.microsoftonline.us/MY TENANT ID/oauth2/v2.0/token
            [urlResourceOwnerDetails:League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider:private] => https://graph.microsoft.us/oidc/userinfo

However, I find that when I test GraphPhpLeagueAuthenticationProvider, the same URL's relfect the Global URL's with .com addresses! So some aspect of GraphPHPLeagueAuthenticationProvider isn't respecting the NationalCloud parameter.

The example says it uses an interactive authentication provider. But you're using a confidential client, so no user authentication is done. The error is quite clear that this isn't supported for cross-cloud requests. So I guess it authenticates on the public cloud and then tries to pull resources from the government cloud. https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/166064#issuecomment-1719236708 may be relevant (different code library, but maybe same basic root cause, if I had to guess). Sorry I don't know exactly, just trying to infer from the info provided here and online about the error

It's not intended to be an interactive login, and an example of the client connection I am using is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=PHP#client-credentials-provider

Added hopefully a bit more information and context to the root of my issue. I hope that is enough for someone to suggest a way to work with this library.

It's not intended to be an interactive login...no I know. My point was that you said "I've used this example" and then linked to an example which says The following example configures an Interactive authentication provider, but then are actually using a non-interactive authentication method in your code. So I just wondered if you'd realised that.
